# RoR: ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Attendee must exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, migration, many-to-many, associations

I am trying to make a **many-to-many** association in an RoR program, but I can't get rid of the error I mentioned in the title, the command I am using in the Rails console is:

```
User.find(1).attended_events = [Event.find(1)]
```

I need to solve this problem and can't find anywhere, I appreciate any help.

**My code:**

**Models**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :created_events,class_name:"Event"
  has_many :hosts
  has_many :attended_events, through: :hosts
end
```

```
class Host < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :attended_event, class_name:"Event"
  belongs_to :attendee, class_name:"User"
end
```

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :creator, foreign_key: :user_id, class_name:'User'
  has_many :hosts
  has_many :attendees, through: :hosts
end
```

**Migration Files**

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```
class CreateHosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :hosts do |t|
      t.references :attendee, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :attended_event, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :event_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.string :date
      t.text :description
      t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about the [foreign_key option](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-many-foreign-key) for `has_many`.

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :creator, foreign_key: :user_id, class_name:'User'
  has_many :hosts
  has_many :attendees, through: :hosts
end
```

These model associations are wrong, the error is in the second line.

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :creator, foreign_key: :user_id, class_name:'User'
  has_many :hosts
  has_many :attendees, through: :hosts
end
```

With these model associations, you need to specify the `foreign_key` for the `has_many :hosts` statement.

```
class Host < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :attended_event, class_name:"Event"
  belongs_to :attendee, class_name:"User"
end
```

Here are my suggestions:

**User**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :created_events, foreign_key: 'user_id'
  has_many :hosts, foreign_key: 'attendee_id'
  has_many :attended_events, through: :hosts
end
```

**Host**

```
class Host < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :attended_event, class_name: 'Event'
  belongs_to :attendee, class_name: 'User'
end
```

**Event**

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :hosts, foreign_key: 'attended_event_id'
  has_many :attendees, through: :hosts
end
```

**Your hosts migration**

Better avoid passing the `foreign_key` here, it will look for an `attendees` table and a `attended_events` table in the database.

```
class CreateHosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :hosts do |t|
      # t.references :attendee, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :attendee, null: false
      # t.references :attended_event, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :attended_event, null: false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Define `source` on through association

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :created_events, class_name:"Event"
  has_many :hosts
  has_many :attended_events, through: :hosts, source: :event
end


class Host < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
end


class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :creator, foreign_key: :user_id, class_name:'User'
  has_many :hosts
  has_many :attendees, through: :hosts, source: :user
end


class CreateHosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :hosts do |t|
      t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :event, null: false, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can do 
`User.find(1).attended_events << Event.find(1)`